# Check if element has class on click of another element and run a function

Tags: javascript, html

Vanilla JS. Trying to run a function on click of an element if the body tag has a class of `example`. No `jQuery` solutions please, I come from `jQuery` and want to learn and understand this simple task in `JavaScript`.

More so if you care to let me know, where is the error in my thinking please? Do I need to wrap the `onclick` event inside the condition for the body class? [Tried that but also not getting the alert](https://jsfiddle.net/z6yad20p/1/).

```js
    var imgContainer = document.querySelector('.img-container');

    var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

    var bodyClassName = bodyTag.classname;

    imgContainer.onclick = infoBox;

    function infoBox(event) {

      if (bodyTag.classList.contains("example")) {

        alert('img-container has been clicked');

      }
    }
```

```html
<body class="example">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x120/000/fff" alt="dummy image">
    <div class="img-infobox">
      <p>This is a dummy image from https://dummyimage.com/</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Edit**
From the given answers I am thinking that instead of returning an array like object and querying the DOM it would be fastest to just just `document.body`. no?

And this then means this question does not really have to do with

[What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

since the answer provided by the comment from https://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq uses neither of the methods from the linked answer.

**Also**
How can I compare the speed of using the `document.querySelector` vs. `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];` vs. `document.body` please?

Like to give an explanation why I accepted what answer to be fair as all answers provide a working solution.

**Answer**
Since all answers work and `document.body` [is fastest](https://jsperf.com/body-selector-comparision) but also for another reason I like to post my answer here.

I am using this script from ["4 novel ways to deal with sticky :hover effects on mobile devices"](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/sticky-hover-issue-solutions.shtml#dynamichover) to handle the sticky hover problem. With this a class is added to the `html` tag of the site.

At first I had the click function inside the condition to check for the body or html class and only fire the click functions once the class is met, however with using this script I had to first run the function and only once it is run check if the html/body has the wanted class.

So while

```
  if (bodyTag.classList.contains("example")) {

    imgContainer.onclick = infoBox;

    function infoBox(event) {
        alert('img-container has been clicked and body has class "example"');    
    }
```

as well as

```
var bodyClassName = bodyTag.classname;

imgContainer.onclick = infoBox;

function infoBox(event) {

  if (bodyTag.classList.contains("example")) {

    alert('img-container has been clicked');

  }
}
```

works in a pure JSFiddle, it won't work with this setting since the sticky hover script sets the desired class on the element once a touch is made.

So once a click is made (I assume) it is then already too late to check for a condition outside of this touch/tap/click event and hence it won't fire.

In the end this leads to these simple lines that work together fine with the sticky hover script. The click event must run first and then check for the desired class/condition.

```
var imgContainer = document.querySelector('.img-container');

imgContainer.onclick = infoBox;

function infoBox(){

    if (document.documentElement.classList.contains('can-touch')) {
        alert('click on touch');
    }
}
```

Comment: `var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];`: https://jsfiddle.net/z6yad20p/2/

Comment: Or simply `var bodyTag = document.body;`

Comment: [`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName): "_Returns an **HTMLCollection of elements** with the given tag name._"

Comment: So the `[0]` tells it to look for the first item in the array, but why when there is only one `body` tag? Do I need to explicitly declare that I am looking for the first `body` tag in the collection of elements even if there is only one element in the collection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: You can access body directly without querying DOM at all as `document.body`.

Comment: @dfsq I shall do just that then instead of running a second query on DOM.

Comment: Up to you. I would say that it's preferred. But it's good that you learned about `document.getElementsByTagName` being a collection too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selector used for selecting body element is not appropriate.

getElementsByTagName will give an array like object so you will have to use index to get the first element.

Read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

you are already using querySelector which return the first matching element , do the same for body as well.

Read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```js
var imgContainer = document.querySelector('.img-container');

var bodyTag = document.querySelector('body');

var bodyClassName = bodyTag.classname;

imgContainer.onclick = infoBox;

function infoBox(event) {

  if (bodyTag.classList.contains("example")) {
  
    alert('img-container has been clicked and body has class "example"');
    
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="example">

  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x120/000/fff" alt="dummy image">
    <div class="img-infobox">
      <p>This is a dummy image from https://dummyimage.com/</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Performance Comparision : https://jsperf.com/body-selector-comparision

Comment: How can I compare the speed of using the `document.querySelector` vs. `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];` vs. `document.body` please? Like to give an explanation why I accepted what answer to be fair.

Comment: best performance will be document.body because it does not involve any selector parsing. including a test run link for your code for all of these selector with your code.

Comment: Thank you. Went for your answer since you were just now also super quick to provide the performance link and you answered first.

Answer (score 2):

The `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which can be accessed as an array of objects, all you need is to select the first by using `[0]` after it like the following example:

```js
var imgContainer = document.querySelector('.img-container');

    var bodyTag = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    var bodyClassName = bodyTag.classname;

    imgContainer.onclick = infoBox;

    function infoBox(event) {

      if (bodyTag.classList.contains("example")) {

        alert('img-container has been clicked');

      }
    }
```

```html
<body class="example">
  <div class="img-container">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x120/000/fff" alt="dummy image">
    <div class="img-infobox">
      <p>This is a dummy image from https://dummyimage.com/</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "*The document.getElementsByTagName returns an array of objects*" – no,  it's not true, it doesn't return an array.

Comment: @dfsq It return a collection of elements, in an object then?

Comment: Yes, it's HTMLCollection, but it's not an array.

Comment: @dfsq It returns a `live collection` which acts like an array

Comment: Not really, you don't call string "Hello world" an array, right? However, it acts like an array as much as `document.getElementsByTagName`. So it's better  to avoid calling it as array. Anyway, no big deal, i'm in troll mood. Cheers!

Comment: @dfsq Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Had a look at this [jsperf test](https://jsperf.com/body-selector-comparision) and the method you use is actually 2nd fastest, though `document.body` fastest.